# Possible connection of a badly written loss function and the size of a torch tensor

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, storage

I am currently doing a project where I will train a variable x to minimize the loss function f(x). The loss function is the MMD of gaussian kernel.

I will store the history of x during the iteration in x_history and save x_history as a .pt file with torch.save. Before I save x, I will first transform x into a numpy array by x.detach().numpy() and then append it to the list x_history.
I have two versions of code with every other part being exactly the same except for the loss funciton used to train x.

One version is using a loss funciton I write myself without any special treatment.
The other version is I call geomloss.sampleloss() to generate the MMD function as the loss funciton.

However, the .pt file generated by my code usually is a lot larger (mine usually takes GBs to save while the other only need MBs) then the code generated by geomloss. I numerically checked my loss function is outputing the same numerical value as geomloss.sampleloss(). So what could be the possible reason of my data is so large.